# drawContours strange behaviour?

Tags: opencv, contour

I filter small blobs from binary image(contours that have area smaller then threshold).
mask is binary image.

If I comment line

```
 drawContours(mask, contours, -1, Scalar(255), CV_FILLED, 8);
```

then I get strange results when I save mask after fill with 0 small blobs.

Also don't understand why it works when line is uncommented,because after

```
drawContours(mask, contours, -1, Scalar(255), CV_FILLED, 8);
```

mask logically should be same as input mask(except 1 pixel bounding border around image)

```
void FilterSmallBlobs(Mat &mask, float minArea)
{
    //as side effect this code extends inner holes with 1 pixel border and removes 1 pixels border from image border.

    vector<vector<Point>> contours;
    //findContours(mask, contours, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
    findContours(mask, contours, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

    vector<vector<Point>> badContours; //contours to erase
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)contours.size(); i++)
    {
        if(contourArea(contours[i]) <= minArea)
            badContours.push_back(contours[i]);
    }

    //drawContours(mask, contours, -1, Scalar(255), CV_FILLED, 8);
    drawContours(mask, badContours, -1, Scalar(0), CV_FILLED, 8);
}
```

what I get 
[image]
[image]

what I want

[image]
[image]

So I don't understand whe drawContours corrupt initial mask when I fill bad contours?

Comment: Use mask.clone() in findCountours, or mask will be modified and will show that strange artifact

Comment: @Miki don't understand how it can help, I need to modify mask, I fill bad contours with 0.

Comment: `findContours` modifies the input image `mask`. You see the modified part only "under" the big blobs that you didn't draw (you commented that line). Use `findContours(mask.clone(), ...` and will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the documentation for [findContours](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?#findcontours)

> **Note:** Source image is modified by this function.

So, in your case, you are seeing some parts of the modified image, while other parts are *covered*, since you draw the small blobs as black.

This snippet of code should clarify this:

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Mat1b img = imread("path_to_image", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

    vector<vector<Point>> contours;

    Mat1b will_be_modified = img.clone();
    findContours(will_be_modified, contours, RETR_LIST, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (contourArea(contours[i]) < 3000)
        {
            drawContours(img, contours, i, Scalar(0), CV_FILLED);
        }
    }

    imshow("img", img);
    imshow("After findContours", will_be_modified);
    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

[image]

Image passed to `findContours`:

[image]